# Is the Green Goblin a split personality of Norman Osborne or a separate malevolent entity?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, spider-man-2002

In the 2002 *Spider-Man* movie, Norman "talks" to his alter-ego who gives him advice on how to kill Spider-Man (strike at the heart) and it is obvious that he is part of Norman's fractured psyche.

However at the end of the 2004 movie, long after he is dead, he appears to Harry in the mirror and, seemingly inadvertently, leads him to the Goblin gas, glider and armour. Harry was one seriously crazed up fruitloop, but at that point, he had not been exposed to goblin gas, so it’s unlikely his psyche would split, manifest himself as his father and lead him to the secret goblin cache.

So is Norman's goblin consciousness lingering as a ghost or malevolent spirit?

Comment: To be fair, head-Norman didn't exactly say, "Hey Harry, come down this secret passageway to find all my stuff." It told Harry to avenge his father and appeared in a mirror that Harry broke, revealing the secret passageway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe. But probably not.

After Norman dies, we only see him in this one scene, where Harry is alone and somewhat distraught. We don’t see this “spirit” take any actions that are witnessed by a third party. We also don’t see any other examples of spirits or supernatural activity in the Spider-Man trilogy.

Harry had a troubled relationship with his father in the first Spider-Man movie. He felt unvalued by him, and somewhat jealous of his father’s admiration of Peter. In the second movie, Harry has tried and failed to take revenge on Spider-Man for his father’s death. He has this vision in his father’s house. I think it’s meant to represent his father’s profound effect on his mind, rather than anything supernatural.

Comment: We see a lot of supernatural activity in the Spider-Man trilogy.

Comment: @Adamant: we do? Was Peter bitten by a *magic* spider?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: @Adamant - Listen bud, he's got *radioactive* blood.

Comment: Now, now, let's not bicker and argue over what bit whom....

Answer (score -2):

I think Norman Osborn has a split personality in other words Norman Osborn and the Green Goblin are two separate people but the same person.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is how Norman's alter-ego can appear to Harry.  It would also be helpful if you provided evidence (references) in your answer.